# How to change max size attachments in apache james?

Tags: apache, size, email-attachments, james

How can I know how much is the default maximum size of attachments in apache james and how i can change its value?

Example: I open inbox folder via  imap, and i want append mimeMessage to this folder, but when i add 340 kb attachment to mimeMessage and do append this mimeMessage to folder , but james no answer, java wait answer. I thing it is related to max size attachment.

Anyone have any idea? Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Hi, am also have same problem any solutions?

Comment: No, I don't found solution

Comment: thanks for the response, Then how u solve this problem? any suggestions?

Comment: Then we switched to another mail server

Comment: @mathi did you find the response in the meanwhile ? :)